# Rake db:seed is breaking my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm actually facing a big issue regarding the database migration and the seed of it.
I have a `formes` table which contain 2 fields, `name` and `country_id`. I recently needed to add a `code` field inot it, so I did :

```
class AddCodeToFormes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :formes, :code, :string
  end
end
```

So far so good, the migration pass with success using `rake db:migrate`. Then in my `seeds` file, I wanted to add the new column in order to fill in the new datas. Here is my file :

```
country = Country.create!( code: 'US', name: 'USA' )    
Forme.delete_all
Forme.create!( name: '-', country_id: country.id, code: '-' )
Forme.create!( name: 'item 1', country_id: country.id, code: 'PARTICULIER' )
Forme.create!( name: 'item 2', country_id: country.id, code: 'PATENTE' )
Forme.create!( name: 'item 3', country_id: country.id, code: 'SARL' )
Forme.create!( name: 'item 4', country_id: country.id, code: 'EURL' )
```

Then, I ran `rake db:seed` as I did the first time for fill in the database. It's works without errors and the data are populated with success into the database.

But then, when I'm trying to access my application, I've got an error when trying to access associate data such as : `@contact.forme.code`

And then, when I recreate the database, it works like a charm. So what did I do wrong?

EDIT :
An information who might be useful, I don't know, is that my mysql database engine is InnoDB. As I said in my comments, there is no visible errors and the database looks fine but ActiveRecord can't anymore handle associations

EDIT 2 :
Without the `code` value in my `seeds.rb`, it works like a charm

EDIT 3 :
Rails actually give me an error when accessing the page : `undefined method 'code' for nil:NilClass` on `@contact.forme.code`

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what the error actually is, and the code you are using to get it.

Comment: breaking means anything can you please show the errors

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your answers. That's the thing actually, there is no visisble error, everything seems fine, but then it breaks my association, right after that seeds. The problem come from the database because when I recreate it, it actually works again

Comment: @user1965817 try my answer, your problem is that you can't do your seed file like that.

Comment: Then please explain what it means: "it breaks the association". `@forme.country` is `nil`? Check the value of `country_id`. Is it nil or zero. Does the country exist after the seed?

Comment: The country exists and all the association are good in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally make it works. I'm using :

```
rake db:setup
```

which drop the database, create tables and seed it. Now it works well. Apparently, we can't just use `rake db:seed` itself.

Thanks to everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't use the country id, but refer to the country object itself when creating Forme?

```
country = Country.create!( code: 'US', name: 'USA' )    
Forme.delete_all
Forme.create!( name: '-', country: country, code: '-' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I always like using the [tap](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/tap) method for seeds.rb. This works:

```
Country.create!( code: 'US', name: 'USA' ).tap do |country|
  Forme.delete_all
  Forme.create!( name: '-', country_id: country.id, code: '-' )
  Forme.create!( name: 'item 1', country_id: country.id, code: 'PARTICULIER' )
  Forme.create!( name: 'item 2', country_id: country.id, code: 'PATENTE' )
  Forme.create!( name: 'item 3', country_id: country.id, code: 'SARL' )
  Forme.create!( name: 'item 4', country_id: country.id, code: 'EURL' )
end
```

Once you're inside that block, the country object is available for use, so you can associate the 'forme' and the 'country'.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it's not working as well. As I said, there is no visual error and the database looks fine.

Comment: whats your models like? Does a form has_one country or belongs_to a country?

Comment: I have a `belongs_to :country`

Comment: This is a nice refactoring, but not essential and does not change a thing. He defined `country` in the seed, so it will set it correctly.